# Is there a program to enumerate windows?

Tags: windows

I'm having problems with a third-party program which is using FindWindow() to find if another process is started.

Where can I find an already-compiled program which enumerate windows (using EnumWindow()) so that I can quickly find what's going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you need a free alternative, try [Winspy++](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy), [Minispy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/minispy.aspx) or [Winspector](http://www.windows-spy.com/)

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried Spy++?